# How can I find out the number of recovery points defined in Hyper-V replication

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-virtualization

I'm reviewing a Hyper-V replication job that was setup by a former consultant. The replication job is working fine, I'm just trying to find out the number of recovery points that were defined when the replication was created. Does anyone know how I can find out using Powershell or another method, I can't seem to find it?

I tried the Get-VMReplication commandlet but don't see this info in the output

Answer (score 0):

I made an account today in case you or anyone else is still looking for this answer.

On the primary host, open the settings for a replicated VM. Under the Management section, expand Replication and open Recovery Points.

[screenshot of Recovery Points options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwnAV.png)